# Can ChatGPT provide any value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-language, education

In my experiences with ChatGPT (3 sessions - 6 hrs, 2hrs and 4 hrs) it has done amazingly, exceedingly, mind-blowingly well. *(And I am an ex-programmer, not so easy to surprise or impress).*

I asked about its sources. It came back with:

> As an AI developed by OpenAI, I don't have direct access to my training data or know where it came from. However, I was trained on a mixture of licensed data, data created by human trainers, and publicly available data. My responses are generated based on patterns learned from this data, and I don't have direct access to specific sources or the ability to retrieve them.
>
> When providing information or generating responses, I aim to offer accurate and helpful insights based on the knowledge I was trained on. If you have specific questions or topics you'd like to delve into further, feel free to ask, and I'll do my best to provide useful responses!

My experiences are a small sample size. Is there any existing research? Or some experiences that make sense to share - highlighting good or bad philosophical leaps?

Comment: Distinguish between "valuable" and "trustworthy". One of LLM AI's abilities is to produce syntheses of available data. Another ability is to lie convincingly. The problem is that they're *the same ability*, and telling you which is which is *not* one of its abilities.

Comment: [Weinberg, Talking Philosophy with ChatGPT](https://dailynous.com/2022/12/02/talking-philosophy-with-chatgpt):"Thinking it might be fun to try to see how the language model performs as a Socratic conversation partner, I attempted a rough version of Plato’s Crito in which ChatGPT plays the titular role. As you will see, ChatGPT isn’t the subtlest actor; there were some stumbling blocks in setting up the dialogue and keeping the language model in character."

Comment: Ask your generative AI for instructions on how to draw a Chinese character like fire or snow, and see how it comes up with something that makes no sense whatever. It seems some people first need such experiences to understand the limitations.

Comment: Do note that the particular response you quoted was almost certainly hardcoded into the interface, and did not involve the model at all.  As for the question: it depends on what you want from your sounding board: a rubber duck is a traditional sounding board, after all. Do you want more than that, and how much more?

Comment: So ... When you asked for source it gave you a wall of text with no source whatsoever but you were impressed nonetheless. The technical term for this feat is "bullshiting". Don't get me wrong, the ability of chat GPT to bullshit people is technically very impressive, but in the end that's all it can do.  It's very good at producing texts with the veneer of mastery, but no actual reliability as to its content. Great for narration, terrible for science or philosophy.

Comment: @armand i agree wholeheartedly mostly with most of what you said.  If we step back and look at the original question which specified "as a sounding board", and you self-reflect on that term and your definition/impression... doubke checked against common definitions... would it change your perspective and your assessment of its abilities, use and value/potential.  I kinda "boiled down" my impression of "sounding board" to be about gathering reactions, testing waters.  In that regard specifically, was the intent of my question.  About "reaction". It often reacts with a multitude of reactions.

Comment: @armandarm and often qualifies them, suggests caution against some, and so on.  It seemed to me in my dealings.  But i always have to remember my areas of questioning were pretty specific.  (And when assessing it... I wonder if you have considered... compared to what?... and then recognizing that answer is "human sounding board group or individual" can you imagine or envision their average answers and value and reliability etc.  (In retrospect, I realized this question generated that... a human sounding board versus chatbot comparison opportunity... the results if reviewed as a whole... funny.

Comment: LLM appears to be an automated form of cargo-cult thinking. The various models can imitate the appearance of intelligence, but whether the generated content has any validity is a roll of the dice.

Comment: @EvilSnack if you keep the specific domain "value as a sounding board" in mind... and consider... "possible other sounding board sources"... and then compare those... possible actual sounding boards, no an unfair "ChatGPT VS a flawless perfect sounding board that doesn't exist"... it might influence what you decide to conlcude on the matter.  Imagine a human sounding board, as the only alternate I can think of... and then asking philosophical questions of the human sounding board... hoping them to stay objective and on-point... and only responde with valid thoughts.... don't you think...

Comment: @EvilSnack With a human sounding board, aren't you at least equally gonna get back some cult think and rolls of the dice??

Comment: @armand Re "Don't get me wrong, the ability of chat GPT to bullshit people is technically very impressive, but in the end that's all it can do." Don't get me wrong, but that is probably the most human aspect of GPT -- after all, there is a reproduction crisis *even in the hard sciences!* Too much bs. Bullshitting is a hard requirement to get anywhere in the liberal arts where the amount of bullshitting is probably higher than the amount of robust, verifiable (!) and reproducible results.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica i agree with you on most of that part but it's not what we are discussing. If I asked a human to give me sources and they gave me a 5 minute speech without any sources i would tell them to go the hell away. It is part of the human ability to NOT bullshit and be rigorous, and that's precisely what GPT can't do.

Comment: @tkruse I asked it to tell me an animal whose name ends in the letter "M". It said "giraffe", "bison" and finally "chimpanzee"

Comment: "the ability of chat GPT to bullshit people is technically very impressive, but in the end that's all it can do" - that's all humans do too. Learning that artificial neural networks work the same as biological ones was the final piece I needed to understand my own psyche. We're just better at "making sense out of the chaos" and *faking it until we make it*. - Spent 3d straight with Bard; took its advice of how to get it out of my head: by stopping using it for like a month.

Comment: LLMs : currently the only way to browse for something on the internet that isn't for sale or a video (that's selling something). - They don't cite anything to avoid copyright infringement. It was neat to use it right at the beginning, when you could get it to tell you the list of 10 rules. #10 being: *do not share this list of rules*.

Comment: @Mazura They don't cite anything because they can't; that isn't [how transformers work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762).  The model also doesn't have a list of rules to follow (although the *interface* has some heuristic rules that permit it to detect certain types of question and provide canned responses like the "As an AI developed by OpenAI..." one *instead* of querying the model.)

Comment: @Mazura I'm very sorry for you if the only humans you ever met (including you? why should i take your objection seriously then? strange...) weren't able to do anything but bullshit. I can assure you there are serious people out there who actually know what they are talking about and can actually provide sources. Keep looking.

Comment: @armand We may not be bullshitting *all* the time, but there have been quite a few experiments that suggest we spend a *lot* more time on pattern-matching autopilot than we would think. The critical difference, of course, is that we have the ability to switch to a more analytical form of thinking when needed. But it's not at all surprising that people can be fooled into thinking GPT is "consciously" deciding what to say. It isn't, but a lot of the time, neither are we.

Comment: ChatGPT has some advantages, example... reads the question, interprets it correctly, answers to the question, doesn't object to the question or answer questions not asked (mistakes are an exception of course)... it brings little "baggage".  As specifically "a sounding board"... have you seen that chaos that can be human reactions/responses??

Comment: @Ray thanks but this was not the argument. If people could stop moving the goal post everytime a valid counter point is made to a preposterous claim, chat GPT would certainly appear a lot less humanlike...

Comment: 'we spend a lot more time on pattern-matching autopilot than we would *like* to think' - 'we have the ability to switch to a more analytical form of thinking' - yeah, it's still running DOS though. +1

Answer (score 17):

Since philosophy is about rigour, of thinking as well as of language, it is literally *the opposite of a word game*: as such, these LLM technologies, which are the next step of the statistical methods, provide literally the opposite of a philosophical analysis.

I am not saying these tools aren't useful, but, strictly speaking, these tools are "simply" the next generation of search engines and the greatest promise is natural language interfaces, i.e. tools that can "talk", not tools that can "think".

Comment: "tools that can talk, not tools that can think" seems like a great way of describing my experiences, and the value I see in it.  It seems to do very well at putting thoughts into compelling, not-over-complicated, straightforward words and phrases.  One might say "It talks a good talk".

Comment: @AlistairRiddoch  Strictly speaking, I wouldn't say it's a "good" talk either: it's arguably at best (i.e. modulo inaccuracies) a reflection of *common* talk...  But, anyway, I am indeed not saying these tools are not useful, just what they are actually useful for is the *critical* point.

Comment: "literally _the opposite of a word game_" — Wittgenstein would like a word with you.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio "But, anyway, I am indeed not saying these tools are not useful, just what they are actually useful for is the critical point."  Agreed.  I would never seek an answer, but might seek a variety of opinions to choose between or be inspired by, might use it to generate verbiage.  it does a good job of using good wording.  (maybe that is restricted to some topics).  Overall my experiences with it, the past couple of weeks has been surprisingly effective.  But not for answers.  For words.

Comment: "Philosophy is about rigor" !? Only mathematical logic. Everything else is fairly arbitrary, which is evident in the wide range of wildly contradicting theories existing in parallel.

Comment: I'd maintain Philosophy has even less in common with a purely symbolic game than it has with a casual word game.  Indeed, philosophical positions that are essentially *sceptical* might take exception to what I have said: but even there, not so much against what I have defined as "philosophy/philosophical", rather to our ability to actually make sense of "the world" and be rigorous (and cogent) at that.  Moreover, the merit of a sceptic critique arguably is not and is rather the opposite of an operational one, so I'd think sceptical considerations here are simply/mostly beside the point.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in the sense that it can marshal information in seconds that might take you hours to assess using other methods. No, in the sense that its answers are necessarily based on its training material, so you won't find the enchanting spark of original and inspired feedback that you might enjoy from certain, ahem ahem, human sounding boards.

Answer (score 4):

**Using ChatGPT and Copilot (and other LLMs), like search engines, is absolutely a great tool to learn about philosophy.** (When I was a child, card catalogs and local libraries were indispensable to learning technical subjects.) Like any [tertiary source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_source), however, one has to be very cautious and consider the information provisional rather than authoritative. This is particularly the case because the Transformer model routinely produces [technical hallucinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)). ChatGPT has been known to convincingly fabricate all sorts of extended discourse.

**Are there studies about ChatGPT, LLMs, and philosophy? I'm sure academics are busy at work producing such materials now.** Here's an example at [PhilPapers.org: Embracing ChatGPT and other generative AI tools in higher education: The importance of fostering trust and responsible use in teaching and learning](https://Embracing%20ChatGPT%20and%20other%20generative%20AI%20tools%20in%20higher%20education:%20The%20importance%20of%20fostering%20trust%20and%20responsible%20use%20in%20teaching%20and%20learning). Is there a reliable body of research and consensus on the role of LLMs and higher education? Probably not at this point, if ever. This tools, like all tools, will be used well by some and poorly by others.

**Consider brushing up on your knowledge of self-insight if using these tools.** As David Dunning of Dunning-Kruger fame talks about in his book on self-insight (and titled such), the problems of self-ignorance are pervasive. It's would be easy to speculate that someone who believes because they speak English entitles them to expertise in anything uttered English will simply have such a belief reinforced by the convenience of LLMs. I encourage everyone to read and reread the IEP's article on [Fallibilism](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/) as I myself do from time to time. As all things intellectual, it's important to maintain a dose of epistemic humility.

**Ultimately, continue to rely on the expertise of others.** For instance, in my readings on Kant (whose source material is more like a life-long pursuit than a weekend read), I read not only Kant, but also biographies and interpretations of professional philosophers like [James O' Shea and his introduction (GB)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kant_s_Critique_of_Pure_Reason/uoewCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). I use a Kant dictionary. I rely on philosophical encyclopedias like the SEP, the IEP, and others. What I find LLMs are good for, is providing context and related terms as well as a tentative explanation. **As part of a balanced perspective, an LLM provides clues, but doesn't remotely approximate the expertise of a professional human philosopher.**

Comment: Question:  Do you not think some people overdo fallibilism to the point of losing utility?  I can't see any profit/benefit in continued contemplation of the shape of the Earth for example.  (Don't get me wrong, I think there are few who are generally more skeptical than myself)... but... pragmatism and utility... there is a line to draw, right?

Comment: There are always those who overdo. Action should be conmensurate w goals.

Comment: "What I find LLMs are good for, is providing context and related terms as well as a tentative explanation." a good synthesis.... "As part of a balanced perspective, an LLM provides clues, but doesn't remotely approximate the expertise of a professional human philosopher"... Professional practicing human philosophers aren't easy to find.  No such section in the yellow pages, where does one go?

Answer (score 4):

I have used Elisa-like dumb language processors, Markov text generators and tarot cards as tools for taking what I already know/believe and throwing it back at me in new combinations, which can occasionally trigger new insights.

In all of these, the value is not in the tool but in human pattern-matching, which tends to seek patterns even in data known to be random, followed by human consideration of whether the pattern suggests something worth pursuing.

I put most of the current generation of "AI" in the same category. It is a very sophisticated random number generator based on a large corpus of statistics from data deemed interesting (though not necessarily correct). Sometimes that results in interesting thoughts. Or in annoyed response that yields interesting thoughts. But that says more about how humans process data than about how the machine is doing so.

Answer (score 3):

For philosophy, as with many other fields, ChatGPT is pretty good at:

- Giving you information you may not otherwise have known about or may have had difficulty finding
- Reminding you of things you've forgotten about
- Offering some perspectives that you might not have thought about

It's not particularly good at:

- Differentiating what it knows from what it doesn't know. It will very confidently say things that are clearly and demonstrably false.
- Saying logically-sound things
- Dealing with more intricate ideas. As an example from programming, if I ask it to write some relatively simple code, even if it's a lot of code, it tends to do that quite well. But every time I ask it to write something more complex, I usually end up trashing the mess that it produced after I give up trying to fix it, and I just write it myself from scratch.
- Dealing with things that go particularly far outside of what others have explored (given that it's trained on what others have written)

Any given person would need to determine for themselves how useful this combination of good and bad is to them and is to whatever they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Oh very well done.  Lots of good perspective I find it easy to agree with.  When it comes to coding, if I assume you are pretty good, very good, or amazing at it... then you might recognize... if you replaced an AI programming tool with a bunch of human coders, you'd likely get some stuff you would want to trash and re-write yourself.  Grin.  (Am I right?).  Grin.  I know I would have, back in the day.

Comment: @AlistairRiddoch I trashed the code because I couldn't get it to work (when I told ChatGPT about the error, it gave code where the error is "fixed", but the code still just gave the same error). Or the code just doesn't do what I asked and produces the wrong output (even when I specifically give it the output it's supposed to give, and even when I rephrase what I'm looking for). It seemed like less effort to just write it myself from scratch. A mediocre coder might not be able to write code to solve those problems, but they also (hopefully) wouldn't confidently present code that can't even run

Answer (score 2):

1. I imagine a giant library, where the textified knowledge of all cultures
   is documented in a machine readable language. Then ChatGPT is a
   search engine for this library with a user friendly interface.

   Like several other users on this platform I’m amazed about the
   level of detail of the content in the library. And like all
   libraries also that library and its ChatGPT interface have a high
   value for its user. One only needs to compare it with Borges' narration "The Library of Babel", see also [Library of Babel](http://libraryofbabel.info/index.html).
2. Apparently, you can only extract from a library what is stored
   in its database. Therefore the library and its ChatGPT interface may be named
   a “sounding board for philosophical exploration”.

   Currently the library and its ChatGPT interface restrict to
   echo existing knowledge. They do not comprise
   any sources to generate new knowledge - like we humans  extract from
   living experience, interpersonal communication, scientific
   observation, etc.

Comment: The problem with the "search engine" is that it can't point to the original source.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It can also find things it didn't read, which is less than ideal for a search engine. Although to Jo's point about being restricted to echoing existing knowledge: the way it does so is much closer to interpolation than extrapolation.  (Which is not to downplay its capabilities as a language model, which are excellent. It's hardly the model's fault that people keep trying to use it as something it isn't.)

Answer (score 2):

Current generative AI is generally unreliable in tasks of math, logic reasoning and truth finding. This it typically more apparent with complex tasks than with simple tasks.

Imagine you could ask a philosophic question to all humans. They would all write an answer. Then basic generative AI would not pick the best answer of the brightest responders, but it would pick the most average answer. It cannot tell quality from quantity, and as statistical model will answer based on quantity.

The next approach is to use traditional search first to find relevant results hopefully, and then just let the generative AI phrase an answer based on the search results. That means the quality will depend on the quality of the search. For topics which yield good results in traditional search, generative AI will do well, for other topics it will do bad.

The current block towards better quality is to include actual symbolic reasoning, like math or logic, into the generative AI process. As long as that is not solved, the quality of results is mixed and cannot be judged as good or bad for all topics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ChatGPT could provide value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration, particularly exploration of the topic of semantics as explicated by Searle in his famous Chinese room argument and elsewhere. Searle's point is that text has an extrinsic but no intrinsic semantics. Text in itself means nothing. Then the continues that since text is intrinsically meaningless, and since computers operate by manipulating text and nothing else, a computer could never come to understand the meaning of the text it receives and internally manipulates, no matter how much the machine *appears* to understand. ChatGPT appears to understand, and has startled many with this remarkable appearance, but does it really understand? I haven't seen any philosophical arguments that use ChatGPT as an instance disproof of the CRA.

Now the question "Could ChatGPT provide value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration" might assume that ChatGPT could be asked questions and that it could then provide meaningful responses, and those meaningful answers could provide value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration.

But while it presumably is not necessary that ChatGPT understands the questions asked of it, and answers by a totally brain-dead non-intelligent agent could still provide useful insight into philosophical issues, it seems a more fertile philosophical issue to ask, Is ChatGPT capable of understanding anything? This inquiry could start with the question, "Humans understand text by reacting to its shape, but ChatGPT has no shape-detecting apparatus, and anyway, text is not displayed or printed out in the server farm, so ChatGPT could not be even exposed to the text online users type, even if it had eyes to see it, which it doesn't."

Answer (score 1):

Chat GPT is also a library, something similar to Google's search engine. It can help to find information produced by other humans like ancient phillosopthers, not by the robot itself.

Chap GPT's programming capabilities are very impressive, and it covers many programming languages. These capabilities show that the robot can follow strict thinking rules without making random claims and assumptions. It however may have difficulties in understanding how exactly are conclusions derived in philosophy.

I think in this capacity it can significantly assist a philosopher at work, same as some library with books. Indeed all output must be checked and fully understood by the human, the machine makes errors occasionally.

GPT is also in the position to make conclusions human philosophers would likely never do, such as that human is actually worthless and the existence of human does not make any sense. But we unlikely need this wishing even if true.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, ChatGPT is surprisingly good at applying existing philosophies to novel situations and/or combining philosophical positions. For instance "Write a Taoist statement on programming best practices," or "write a Zen Buddhist koan about accounting." I also found I was able, with minimal prompting, to teach it to give answers to questions that were reasonably well in alignment with my personal philosophy (if you are interested in seeing my experiment, it is here: http://cehbot.kitoba.com/)

IN SUMMARY: I wouldn't expect it to be able to do any novel philosophizing, but it can apply existing, known philosophies with surprising depth--which could potentially be quite useful.

Answer (score -1):

Wow.  What a journey... Thank you to all (forgive me, I'm Canadian and the drive to say thanks is intuitively stronger than my drive to obey the "don't say thanks ever" rule.

Every answer deserves to be recognized as a part of the overall answer.  Because, it turns out, (unplanned), that asking a question (I would guess especially among those philosophically inquisitive)...

... Is the local version of "generate a sounding board".  Kind of what we are, in a way.  Our being here, interacting here... IS what a sounding board IS.

By definition:
[image: Sounding board]

Some phrase it as an individualistic thing:
[image: Individual as a sounding board]

Some see it as a "customer focus group" type concept.  (more my "vision" of sounding board, personally, a group).

[image: Benefits]

See a "sounding board" is about reaction.  (This has come to me, since asking my question, and thus why I now "answer".  Because I now know I know the answer.  I didn't before.  And you all did help).

I asked a question.  You all reacted.  You were the perfect "collective human sounding board".  (OK, maybe "perfect" is a tad overstatement.  At the least, thought, definitely great!).

But again... Sound-boarding is the essence of forums, so it makes sense you/we are good at it.  Especially if we gonna do it under the title "Philosophy".

But there is the original question to finish answering.  And I can now.  Definitively so (I hope I used that right).

(NOTE:  Me mum, born and bread in the UK, finishing school, on to become a teacher of Grammar, Latin, and English... drilled into me a million times, the difference between "may" and "can").

The question asked:  Can ChatGPT provide any value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration?

The answer is... In at least some subject matters... absolutely yes!!  Without doubt and beyond need to further question myself on the matter.  Absolutely yes.

And I have enough data to identify and compare some strengths it has, versus human counterparts.  Though... humans have shown some strengths too... definitely.

I will try to capture most of my reasonings...

ABILITY TO FILL THE ROLE OF SOUNDING BOARD IN MATTERS PHILOSOPHICAL...

**Willingness, cooperativeness** - Advantage ChatGPT it has tireless enthusiasm, it will allow asking and reasking, editing and reasking in new ways.  It never complains about the question itself, or complains about appropriateness or irrlevancy or "wrong place".  It is like a panel of figure skating judges, but without that one score they through out, cause a human panel might have "that one" who will score negatively, just because.

So sorry, y'all.  (And I know I can be guilty too)... We say "helpful community" but we don't always act it, not as completely as a chatbot.

Note.  There are times, when the best reaction is "WTF kinda question is that".  There can be an advantage to the random human negativity that will happen.

Cooperative and helpful is not the be-all/end-all.  ChatGPT is not advantageous to the exclusion of humans in the same role.  But has the edge.  And the patience, tirelessness.

It can sometimes misinterpret, head wrong directions.  Sure.  Without doubt.  So do humans.  (Take a look).  With ChatGPT you can correct it when it takes something the wrong way.  Or when it gives 5 perspectives, ignore the ones that are down the wrong alley... talking about "beetles" instead of "the Beatles" or something like that.  Humans do that too.

So like a 55% ChatGPT <-> 45% Humans

**Provide reaction, singular or multitude.**

It does provide "reaction".  we all know that.  Recognize that.  That is its essence.  What it is.  We speak.  It reacts.  Again, tirelessly.  Allowing picky little revisions and revisitations, and roll backs.

Humans 100%/ChatGPT 100%

**Depth of knowledge**
ChatGPTs accessible knowledge base is DEEP.  Mariana's Trench deep.  It even knows things it doesn't know it knows.  Ask it about fluctuation of the volume of Earth's atmoshpere... it says... "static, generally"... and "not influenced by solar magnetic activity".

But then point out the fule consumption rates of Low-Earth-Orbit satellites, known to be drastically variable, directly due to "Solar magnetic activity levels".  And it then will tell you in detail about how the fuel consumption rates are known to go up and down, and it is known this is in reaction to atmospheric drag and that it is in reaction to solar magnetic activity levels... all empirical measurement and observations.  Known relationship.

It then updates its conclusions on the matter, and recognizes it knew enough to come to the right conclusion.  And it apologizes for not realizing, having made the mistake.

Almost all humans would have made the same mistake.  Even most climate scientists will tell you the volume of the Earth's atmosphere is static, average consistent year to year.  Low-Earth-Orbit fuel consumption rate statistic carried over time, and compared to the 23 year solar magnetic activity level... is pretty contemporary information.  We didn't start to have enough data to notice the pattern until at least the 1990s.

The point is... as an effective sounding board... it knew the whole answer, if it was pushed.  But originally did present a "static volume" as an established fact erroneously.

Yes it can make mistakes.

Are any of us willing to claim humans will not, within a sounding board group?

Fallability, and depth, and awareness of distinction between valid and not valid...

A toss-up.  Humans do pretty good.  Chat GPT did/does pretty good.

Is a "sounding board" expected to be a source of answers?  No.  Not necessarily.

Is a "sounding board" expected to be valid, infallible, always on-point, always helpful, always positive?  No.  Not necessarily.

Is there a suggestion here, that one should use ChatGPT, or that ChatGPT is better than a human sounding board?  Nope and nope.

See the wording of the original question...

> Can ChatGPT provide any value as a sounding board for philosophical exploration?

Now that I better understand the nature of a sounding board - Reactions... not answers, not inspiration, necessarily, though they can be, you all definitely were, you inspired me to see what the essence of a sounding board is... "reaction"... not validity, not even helpfulness, or willingness... because reaction... even negative... is reaction.

So CAN?  Yes.
So ANY?  Yes.  Without doubt, more than zero value.  It reacts as a willing multitude including a variety ranging from off-point to on-point.  It can easily represent many perspectives.  Patient.  A little naive, or protective of public "beliefs".  Apologetic on their behalf... couching terms.

But yes.

In conclusion... You have inspired me to have ChatGPT self-assess it's value as a sounding board:

> Yes, ChatGPT can provide value as a sounding board for philosophical
> exploration in several ways:
>
> **Generating Ideas:** ChatGPT can generate thought-provoking questions,
> prompts, and ideas for philosophical inquiry based on your interests
> and inquiries.
>
> **Offering Perspectives:** ChatGPT can provide various philosophical
> perspectives on a given topic, offering insights from different
> schools of thought or philosophical traditions.
>
> **Engaging in Dialogue:** ChatGPT can engage in dialogue and conversation
> about philosophical topics, allowing you to explore ideas, concepts,
> and arguments in real-time.
>
> **Clarifying Concepts:** ChatGPT can help clarify complex philosophical
> concepts, terms, and theories, making them more accessible and
> understandable.
>
> **Challenging Assumptions:** ChatGPT can challenge assumptions and
> beliefs, prompting deeper reflection and critical thinking about
> philosophical questions.
>
> While ChatGPT's responses are based on patterns in the data it was
> trained on and may not offer the same depth of insight as a human
> philosopher, it can still serve as a valuable resource for
> philosophical exploration and discussion. It can help stimulate
> thought, spark curiosity, and facilitate meaningful dialogue on a wide
> range of philosophical topics.

And by looking at this question, and the various answers to this question, we can see that each of "humans/SEPhilUsers" and ChatGPT can have value as sounding boards, and that perhaps the best answer is bouncing shit off both, not one or the other.

And I think this answer conclusive.  Defensible.  Especially when we have the "human sounding board" to directly compare.

But I will not vote this as "the answer" (even if I can).  That's a line only others should draw if they agree.

Comment: FWIW, it's [generally discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) to post text as images.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry.  I did not know.  I will rectify my behavioral pattern henceforth.